# model a generic pojo to use in my classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, pojo, dto

I'm trying to create an object that works like a generic POJO, since I have to pass it through different objects and I need an interface by which they can access its attributes.

Currently I do it with a base object that has a getField method, where I enter the name of the parameter and I get it through reflection, it's something like this:

```
public abstract class BasePOJO{

    public Object getField(String fieldName){

        try {
            return this.getClass().getField(fieldName).get(this);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BaseRequest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BaseRequest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BaseRequest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BaseRequest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and i use this extending the class like this:

```
public class CredentialsPOJO extends BasePOJO{
    public String username;
    public String password;
}
```

and call the attributes like this:

```
credentialsPojo.getField("username");
```

I have created this quickly, it is horrible but it works. But I want to change it for something more decent to model that object.

También he creado el siguiente:

```
public class BasePOJO{

    private Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();


    public void addParameter(String paramName, Object value){
        parameters.put(paramName, value);
    }

    public Object getParameter(String paramName){
        return parameters.get(paramName);
    }
}
```

I like this object much more, its more OO solution, the problem with this is that it only returns one Object type

The idea is that the objects that use this POJO can access their attributes in a common way.
If there is a design pattern that solves this problem much better, so I can implement it.

Comment: Why do you want to generalize in case when there is no actual gain?
What do you need to achieve?

Comment: I need to generalize it since that object must go through several classes that carry out some process with it, until they reach the target class. I already have that process, I have done it by implementing interceptor pattern.
The common getters and setters do not work for me because the "filter" classes should not be coupled to a specific object, but to an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Terminology clarification**

**POJO** = Plain Old Java Object, that is, it does not use some third-party annotations which are used to "decorate" object behaviour (Hibernate's entity annotations, or already mentioned Lombok which generates methods). What matches your case is **Bean** = class with getters and setters for each class field.

**Solution to your problem**

```
// derive type from left side of the assignement operator
public <T> T getProperty(String paramName){
    return (T) parameters.get(paramName);
}
```

This way, you can type something like this:

```
String name = pojo.getProperty("name");
Integer age = pojo.getProperty("age");
```

**Drawback**

Since given method just explicitly cast map value to "any type on the left side of the assignment operator", there is no way how to achieve **compile-time** checking that will give you warning immediately after you write: `Integer age = getProperty("name");`. Note, there is also runtime type checking, when code is being executed. Such an assignement will throw an `ClassCastException`.

Keep in mind, that as long as you have map defined as `Map<String,Object>` there is no way how to get compile-time checking - value under given key can be virtually anything. This also applies to reflection approach as `getField(String)` returns attribute value hidden in `Object` type.

To get compile-time checking, read **Recommendation** section.

**Recommendation**

I would highly recommend you to use project [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/all), as already mentioned by @Peteef. Make sure you have also installed lombok plugin in your IDE, otherwise auto-generated methods would generate syntax errors.

Annotation [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) will generate getter for each field and setter for each non-final field. In addition `@Data` annotation will generate also `equals` and `hashCode` methods which are important when objects are stored in [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) or [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) collections. Method `equals` might be also desirable if you want to check if two objects are the same (same fields values).

```
@Data
public class Credentials {
    public String username;
    public String password;
}
```

Note, you can still use simple classes with public fields without getters/setters if these classes are supposed to be used as simple data holders. Sure, it's not OOP but you don't have to blindly follow every convention (sometimes they are conter-productive).

```
public class Credentials {
    public String username;
    public String password;
}
```

Comment: Greetings, thanks for replying. I have tried to do it as you have put it, apparently it works, the problem is that it allows me from outside to assign this variable to any type. For example:
String username = request.getParam ("username");
this works, and it is correct, because username is a String.
But it also allows me to do this:
float username = request.getParam ("username");
This also works and it allows me, but the type of output is incorrect.

Comment: @kmilo93sd I have updated my answer by **Drawback** section where is explained why it allows you to write `float username = request.getParam ("username");`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works in PHP (for example Magento - magic methods) and I honestly think it's a terrible mechanism.

Why?

You have no IDE control if field doesn't exist. Your class API is unclear so the risk of mistake is very high. You have to look into implementation to know what fields you can use. In your example you also break encapsulation by making fields public so anyone can use it directly, without your method.

In these days with autogenerated getters/setters there is no need to do it. If you want to get rid of boilerplate getter/setter code, you may use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for example.

Comment: Thank you for responding, you are very right and I agree with you, in fact, the getters and setters were my first choice, but in the practice, I have realized that these are not an option for my problem.
For example, a request object, I need that request to go through several classes that manipulate it and do things with it, all before it reaches the target service.
By using getters and setters would be coupling those classes to a specific request and that would lose their functionality. Currently it works, but that object that I am using is horrible and I want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the verge of creating an [inner platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect). This is generally bad news.

With your generic POJO you won't be able to get support from your IDE when calling methods (because they simply don't exist). Also, you'll run into problems if you forget a field or misspell it. Refactoring will also not be possible without risking issues with the names in strings.

If you're not alone in your project, will your colleagues be able to understand and use this solution? Will you be able to come back to it in 6 months, in a year, in 5 years?

Try as far as possible to simply use property methods (getXyz, setXyz) and call them on objects with different classes depending on their uses.

Look into your IDE, it is likely able to auto-generate getter and setter methods for your fields, so in essence, you only have to set up the fields and then press a button to get the rest done. (IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse does this, too mention two I know of. I am pretty sure Netbeans does as well.)

If you're unsure about what classes you need, create [Use Cases](https://www.incoseonline.org.uk/Documents/Bristol/BLG070328-Use-Case.pdf) for your problem. A good start would then be to create classes for the nouns in the use case texts and methods for the verbs. After that, you can start generalizing. (Although beware of APIs, frameworks, and fits-all-and-everything solutions, even if they are tempting... I love em too! Until I realize I'm building a static site generator instead of printing some HTML-files... usually weeks later...)

Having said all this, there may be frameworks out there to generate classes from database schemas (Hibernate?), web services and the like, and perhaps that's the way to go. Regardless, those are still classes with actual property methods etc.

Hope this helps!